# No result found/Result found

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

i'm new in asking questions here in the site, here is the situation:

- Im using a Xampp Control Panel,
- I have two systems, the old one and the new one (the new one is just the upgraded version of the old one).
- I have 2 databases, let's name it db1 and db2, (db1 is the dbase used for the old one, and db2 is the dbase used for the new one.)
- both databases have the same tables and contents except for one table, in db1.tb_final_dtr the structure has only 10 columns while db2.tb_final_dtr has 11 columns though the 10 columns in each table is the same with each other, and also both tables have the same records.
  -I tried to queried both database with simple query lets say "SELECT * FROM tb_final_dtr WHERE hr_id = 'ASM12-0101'", the problem is, db1 shown 10 records right away, while db2 shown empty result. They both have the same table structure and records, they just differ in database name and the number of columns in one table.

WHAT SEEMS TO BE THE PROBLEM? hope you can reply at my question right away. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Xampp has phpmyadmin why not use it?

Comment: im querying through the pma already and found the problem see my answer below, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your DB_2 is not working on NEW system..

Go to PHPmyadmin (on your NEW system) and add new user with username & password written from your conf file (and server name as localhost) of your website :P

So

- go to PMA
- add new user
- enter data (server, username, password)
- reload mysql

Of course, DB name in config file may also be wrong if tables are duplicated who knows what so check that too.

Good luck!

Comment: same thing happened, but thanks anyway my friend found the error and I validated the error too... the problem was that the hypen in the ID, i tried to edit it and replace it with the same hypen character and it finally worked.